# DIV onload Not Firing JavaScript Method

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have a DIV like this:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;" onload="mapAddress();"></div>
```

Then, in a JavaScript file (**that I've verified is loaded**) is the `mapAddress` function:

```
function mapAddress() {
    //In this case it gets the address from an element on the page, but obviously you  could just pass it to the method instead
    var address = $("#Address").val();

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var myLatLng = results[0].geometry.location.LatLng;

            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatLng,
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: $("#Name").val() + " Location"
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("The location of the event could not be mapped because: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

But for whatever reason it's not being called. Did I misunderstand the `onload` event?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`onload` will not fire for a `<div>` element.

You can do that for the `document` or `body`, or the less desired way of calling the script immediately after the `<div>`.

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
 mapAddress();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. Sorry for my ignorance! Sometimes you wonder, you've been doing this thing for more than a decade and still miss things like this here and there. Just proves we're not perfect.

Answer (score 3):

[onload is only supported by the following HTML Tags](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp):

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, 
<input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't attach `onload` handlers to `<div>` elements, just the `<body>` element.

A good place to put this is directly on the global object (`window`):

```
window.onload = function () {
  // your code
};
```

Placing an `onload` handler on a `<div>` doesn't make sense because the element is "loaded" right after it is parsed and added to the DOM tree.